# Toggle css class using knockout on li tag

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

```
<li class="LightColour">
```

on user select the `li` tag change the `class = "DarkColour"`

How to do this in knockout?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going and reading up on the CSS binding in knockout.
You can do things like:

```
<li data-bind="css: yourComputedVariable">
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Can't really help you more than that as your question is pretty vague, with no code for me to work from.